# Can't run or build my simple app on offline mode

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, offline-caching, offline-mode

I dont have internet connection at my place and im new to this android studio version. I was able to toggle the offline mode but still no luck.

error output here

[image: error output here]

ALSO the settings of my gradle is incomplete. photos attached.

[image: ALSO the settings of my gradle is incomplete. photos attached.]

Thanks guys!

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.1-6040484 available for offline mode.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0):

The offline mode only works if you have resolved once all the dependencies of the project.

If there are missing dependencies that have not been downloaded to your local machine once, they cannot be retrieved from the dependency cache.

So the only solution is to execute at least once the project with an internet connection.